How to acitvate Gurobi in Opensolver Excel
I am a student using OpenSolver in Excel on a Mac for my project, and I have obtained a student license for Gurobi. However, I am encountering an issue with installing and activating Gurobi in OpenSolver. When I try to select Gurobi as the solver, I receive an error message indicating that no Gurobi installation was detected and that the path executable at /usr/bin/python could not be found.
ive tried placing it in the Opensolver folder but that  did not work

OpenSolver is old and unmaintained.  If you wish to persist with it then you need to use Gurobi 9 or earlier (which is no longer officially supported by Gurobi).
https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360048126912/comments/25294279365009

You need to add gurobi executable to your Windows path.
Here is the post describing how to add folder to path: How to add a folder to Path environment variable in Windows 10 (with screenshots)

Do you know how to to this on a mac ?

I do not use mac , but maybe this could be helpful Setting PATH environment variable in OSX permanently
